# Running SQL Agent job for concurrent databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a job that will create a job for all the databases in the SQL instance.  I don't want the jobs to run sequentially.  I need multiple databases to run at once, but I also want to make sure that I don't have too many databases running at the same time that might hinder performance on the server.

Is there a way to specify the number of concurrent jobs that can run at the same time or manage the jobs in a way that new jobs won't get started until the number of active jobs is less than what I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure that accepts the SQL command(s) and the number [n] of jobs you want to run in parallel and let it create & start n jobs, then go into a loop to poll the msdb tables to see if said jobs are still running and each time it notices there are less than n jobs active (or left) it could start a new job until the entire set of databases has been handled. It should then wait for the last one to finish so the calling process knows everything is processed.

tips: 
 - Use the @job_id's returned by sp_add_job to check if a job is still running
 - Use WITH (NOLOCK) on the system tables to avoid unnecessary locking, it doesn't really matter if you'd use 'dirty reads' when looking for the state of the jobs
 - Use WAITFOR DELAY as to only check the tables every 5 seconds or so, otherwise your loop will eat wait too many resources !